# Diff'ing a mixed lists

Tags: python

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, I've done my best to look this up with no success, and I am by no means a Python expert.

I was writing some stuff to "diff" two lists:  basically, compare 2 lists and fill a third list with the common values, while removing them from the original two lists.  So I wrote this:

```
list_1 = ["dog", "cat", "bird", "rabbit", "rabbit"]
list_2 = ["fly", "monkey", "bird", "rabbit", "bear", "rabbit"]
matches = []

for thing in list_1:
    while thing in list_2:
        list_1.pop(list_1.index(thing))
        popper = list_2.pop(list_2.index(thing))
        matches.append(popper)
```

Which gets me:

```
list_1:
['dog', 'cat']
list_2:
['fly', 'monkey', 'bear']
Matches:
['bird', 'rabbit', 'rabbit']
```

That's exactly what I'd expect/want... "rabbit" shows up twice since it's in both lists twice.

But then using the same for loop, this:

```
list_1 = ["dog", "cat", ["bird", "rabbit"], "rabbit"]
list_2 = ["fly", "monkey", ["bird", "rabbit"], "bear", "rabbit"]
```

gets me:

```
list_1:
['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit']
list_2:
['fly', 'monkey', 'bear', 'rabbit']
Matches:
[['bird', 'rabbit']]
```

The second "rabbit" isn't getting added to the matches list, and it remains in the originals. What is going on here that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using sets for this, it will simplify a lot of what you need to do, for example:

```
set_1 = set(["dog", "cat", "bird", "rabbit", "rabbit"])
set_2 = set(["fly", "monkey", "bird", "rabbit", "bear", "rabbit"])

>>> set_1 & set_2   # elements common to both
set(['bird', 'rabbit'])
>>> set_1 - set_2   # elements in set_1 that are not in set_2
set(['dog', 'cat'])
>>> set_2 - set_1   # elements in set_2 that are not in set_1
set(['fly', 'monkey', 'bear'])
```

One of the potential complications here is that you can only put hashable types in a set, so for your second example you would need to first convert the inner lists to tuples:

```
set_1 = set(["dog", "cat", ("bird", "rabbit"), "rabbit"])
set_2 = set(["fly", "monkey", ("bird", "rabbit"), "bear", "rabbit"])

>>> set_1 & set_2
set([('bird', 'rabbit'), 'rabbit'])
>>> set_1 - set_2
set(['dog', 'cat'])
>>> set_2 - set_1
set(['fly', 'monkey', 'bear'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about sets in Python. This is a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

Because when you go through a list, and you remove an element, let say the "n-th", your list becomes "1" item shorter, so the pointer then goes to the "n-th" + 1 element of your new list, which is the "n-th" + 2 of your original. What you could do is in your for loop:

```
for thing in list_1[:]:
   blablabla
```

Then you are looping through a copy of the list, and won't be bothered by that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into an error from editing a list as you are iterating over it.

There is also a potentially fatal bug in this code:

```
while thing in list_2:
    list_1.pop(list_1.index(thing))
```

can result in a `ValueError` if `thing` is in `list_2` more times than it is in `list_1`

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
list_1 = ['dog', 'cat']
list_2 = ['fly', 'monkey', 'bear']
matches = []
for i in list_1:
    if i not in list_2:
        matches.append(i)
```

Method 2:

```
matches = [i for i in list_1 if i not in list_2]
```